# Magento 2.06 php bin/magento setup:upgrade error

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.0, setup, magento-2.0.6

I am trying to install a theme on Magento 2.06. When I try to run the following command: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` but I receive the following error:

```
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in <b>/home/bargaink/public_html/test/bin/magento</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Thanks

HP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, got fixed after talking to my hosting provider.
Do you mind telling me your hosting provider?

try this command:

```
php56 bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

It will then use php version 5.6 which is required in Magento 2. Hope this would help

Comment: I am with Siteground. I tried the command you suggested and it had progressed to the following issue: bin/magento must be run as a CLI application

Comment: Used the following command and solved the issue: /usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli

Comment: I'm also hosting my site with siteground thats what! I ran the command through ssh, and ofcourse if you add cron job etc from cPanel, you have to use full command as you did. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your problem is triggered by this line

```
set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler'])
```

This error is thrown because you're running PHP < 5.4 and the use of `[]` instead of `array()` has been introduced with 5.4

Magento 2 requires PHP 5.6 or PHP 5.5.22 to run properly I reckon you should upgrade PHP to fix that problem.

Magento 2 system requirements: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html